# Python split def function parameter for user input

Tags: python, function, input, user-input

i'm trying to do split def function parameter into two user input then sum up both value then print out.

Example code:

```
def ab(b1, b2):
if not (b1 and b2):  # b1 or b2 is empty
    return b1 + b2
head = ab(b1[:-1], b2[:-1])
if b1[-1] == '0':  # 0+1 or 0+0
    return head + b2[-1]
if b2[-1] == '0':  # 1+0
    return head + '1'
#      V    NOTE   V <<< push overflow 1 to head
return ab(head, '1') + '0'


print ab('1','111')
```

I would like to change "print ab('1','111')" to user input.

My code:

```
def ab(b1, b2):
if not (b1 and b2):  # b1 or b2 is empty
    return b1 + b2
head = ab(b1[:-1], b2[:-1])
if b1[-1] == '0':  # 0+1 or 0+0
    return head + b2[-1]
if b2[-1] == '0':  # 1+0
    return head + '1'
#      V    NOTE   V <<< push overflow 1 to head
return ab(head, '1') + '0'

b1 = int(raw_input("enter number"))
b2 = int(raw_input("enter number"))


total = (b1,b2)

print total
```

My result: 1,111

Expect result:1000

Comment: Please fix your indentation...

Comment: Haven't you just missed the ab call? like total = ab(b1,b2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you're getting the return working here.
First of all (as Daniel) stated, you have the function call missing/improper.

```
total = ab(b1,b2)
```

Secondly, you're type-casting (changing type of input from `string` to `integer`) - and in your function `ab` you're applying string slicing on the `b1` and `b2`, which will result in an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "split_def.py", line 33, in <module>
    total = ab_new(b1,b2)
  File "split_def.py", line 21, in ab_new
    head = ab_new(b1[:-1], b2[:-1])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

---

The final working code has to be:

```
def ab(b1, b2):
    if not (b1 and b2):  # b1 or b2 is empty
        return b1 + b2
    head = ab(b1[:-1], b2[:-1])
    if b1[-1] == '0':  # 0+1 or 0+0
        return head + b2[-1]
    if b2[-1] == '0':  # 1+0
        return head + '1'
    #      V    NOTE   V <<< push overflow 1 to head
    return ab(head, '1') + '0'

b1 = raw_input("enter number")
b2 = raw_input("enter number")

total = ab(b1,b2)

print "total", total
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call your function in the second snippet.

```
total = ab(b1,b2)
```

Comment: Result : TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: So, ask yourself why you are converting those input strings to ints. In the first snippet, you pass strings.